# Disable basic auth for specified hosts in traefik

Tags: docker, http-proxy, traefik

Is it possible to set http basic auth only for specified clients (in docker environemnt)? I'd like to whitelist 192.168.0.0/16 subnet (disable password for local addresses).

And if so - how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Yes u can try this ->
Paste this into your labels and change the IP to ur personal one

`- "traefik.http.middlewares.default-ipwhitelist.ipWhiteList.sourceRange=10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12, 192.168.0.0/16"`

[->here<-](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/ipwhitelist/) is the Documentation from Traefik